# Canvas ScreenShot not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, screenshot

Some time ago, I was able to **take screenshot from my webGL 3D model** using the `toDataURL` function, but suddenly this **stopped working**, and now I am not able to get an image from ***any*** 3D model.

Please see bellow for more insights:

#### ThreeJS examples:

- http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html
- http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry.html

#### WebGL example:

- http://madebyevan.com/webgl-water/

#### basic example:

- http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/HelloWorld.html
- http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson01/index.html

> In all previous examples I didn't get the image, I get either a black or transparent image

#### 2D:

- http://jsfiddle.net/m7sA9/show/

> Only the 2D exemple gave back the correct image

#### In all previous examples I use this simple method to get the image.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL();
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

---

I've tried this on a MacBook Pro: Chrome and FireFox, and on FireFox on Windows 8.1 and I got the same result

#### following is a animation on how I made the tests on Chrome

[image]

Comment: Can u post the relevatnt html + js? What do you get when you console `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]`

Comment: Actually its more like a global problem here, all I am doing is visiting the url opening the console, typing that js line, and I get a base64 image link to open inside the browser

Comment: See if the entire thing is base64 or whether the image type is appended in front of it. Further try cop-pasting the entire thing to something like http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/ and see if u get the image.

Comment: I've added a small screenshot animation on how I test on chrome, please check it out

Comment: @RoyMJ, thanks for your comment, but I don't think the problem is in the base64 image code, since the 2D drawing are working fine, or am I mistaken something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a fix for this problem in my Threejs app, the solution was as simple as putting a flag to true, so in my threejs instanciation I added `preserveDrawingBuffer`:

```
var renderer   = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  preserveDrawingBuffer   : true   // required to support .toDataURL()
});
```

And this is it for the model that uses ThreeJs, so I think the problem is related to a configuration setting and there must be some option for using plain WebGl or other libraries.

Thank you for reading, and I hope this helps someone in future.